# How to access a public class method in a Jar file

Tags: java

This might be a dumb question, but somehow i am unable to crack it.

I have create a maven project(Project 1) and defined a public method. I have created the jar(foo.jar) file using **mvn verify**.

```
package com.aaa.bbb;

public class FooClass{
    public void fooMethod(){
        System.out.print("Hello World");
    }
}
```

In another project(Project 2) i added this jar in Eclipse configure build path -> libraries.
I cleaned this project and updated it.
When i wanted to access FooClass and its method it is saying FooClass **cannot be resolved as type**.

```
package com.iii.jjj;

import com.aaa.bbb; //Throwing an error saying the import com.aaa.bbb cannot be resolved
public class TestClass{
    public void printMsg(){
          FooClass obj=new FooClass(); //throwing error here FooClass cannot resolved to a type
    }
}
```

But when i create another class extends FooClass, it is properly identifying.

```
package com.iii.jjj;
public class TestClass2 extends FooClass{ //It is working fine here
}
```

Tried different solutions, but no luck yet. Can someone help?

Comment: Is `FooClass` inside a package (it should)? Did you import it?

Comment: If you using eclipse,  then in Project2, can you type CTRL+SHFT+T & see if you can see `FooClass` , if so, then mostly you have missed import in project2.

Comment: see first comment, but extent to in which packages are the `FooClass` and the one referencing it? (afaik importing a class from the unnamed [aka default] package does not work) Also check the JAR file and its content  under Referenced Libraries in the Package Explorer. Best to include a [mre] in question...

Comment: @AshishPatil, when i try CTRL+SHFT+T, i can able to see FooClass, but when i am trying to import the package in Project 2, the import **** cannot be resolved.

Comment: ok, have you selected jar as `Add External Jars` or `Add Jars` ?, For me, it usually works by selecting add external jars.

Comment: There might be issue with your eclipse. These happens with me also. You can clean build and than do force maven update.

Comment: @AshishPatil I added using External jar.

Comment: @DharmendraBhanushali Tried that, as mentioned in the post, i first clean the project and updated the project. Still seeing this issue.

Comment: I hope there is typo in `package com.iii.jjj` in your modified code? you are missing `;`

Comment: I also thinking missing ";" can be a problem. If not can you please search the project for duplicate classes for FooClass in a different packages? If you given code for TestClass2 is correct then there is no import for the FooClass, then this should taken from another place, not from the jar. Check it

Comment: Sorry friends, as it is sudo code, i missed here, but in my actual class, i have ' ; '

Comment: How is your import statement actually written? Either you import a single class by stating `import com.aaa.bbb.FooClass;` or you import an entire package by stating `import com.aaa.bbb.*`. Your code is using neither of those.

Comment: As the IDE is not suggesting, i have written this line of code import com.aaa.bbb.*; but no luck.

Comment: I suggest you write that in your code in the question as you can easily get the wrong suggestions. With the star the code is correct and we can focus on giving you better suggestions on how to solve your problem.